# Could not allocate a new page for database 'X' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'

Tags: sql-server

I'm importing some data into a table in SQL Server 2016 (13.0.5201.2). The columns are:

```
int, datetime2(7), float, int, datetime, nvarchar(100)
```

so each row doesn't take much space.

The process is using Entity Framework's BulkInsert and inserts few thousands rows at a time. The process has been running for about 12 hours and had imported about 500 million rows. Then this error started to appear and it keeps appearing:

> Could not allocate a new page for database '[DB_NAME]' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

I read answers suggesting: checking disk space, autogrowth settings, reducing number of files in the PRIMARY group, dropping other tables etc. None of these help me because:

1. The DB size is currently 45 GB and there's another 40 GB available on the drive where the ROWS Data file is located.
2. Autogrowth is set to: By 100 MB, Unlimited.
3. There is only 1 file in the PRIMARY group.
4. I can't drop any tables or truncate any data; and I can't see how this would help given that there's space available in the disk drive.

What else should I check/change? Many thanks.

Comment: What about the log file, where is that?

Comment: @DavidG: the log file is on another drive with 80 GB space available, with autogrowth by 50 MB limited to 2 TB

Comment: What edition of SQL Server do you have?

Comment: You may be running into [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-2016-minimal-logging-and-impact-of-the-batchsize-in-bulk-load-operations/), with too much empty space on your pages. Make sure your bulk insert is using an appropriate batch size (ideally, that's "as much as you possibly can, in a heap table").

Comment: @DavidG: it's Enterprise

Comment: @PiotrS Are you sure the database isn't filling up the storage and then being recovered somehow? Or maybe there's an operating system limit somehow?

Comment: Having said that, there might be some issue with an internal object/page allocation table running out of virtual room -- there'd be disk space left, but no way to allocate new pages. Admittedly, I can't recall hearing of a scenario like this and it seems like something someone else would have run into already. As an "it can't hurt" option, consider installing CU7 for SP2 -- your server is about 8 months behind on updates.

Comment: @DavidG: I have a background job that purges old data, but I disabled it while importing; I just double checked that it's not running. What else could be recovering the space?

Comment: @JeroenMostert: That's true, it's on CU2 for SP2. I'll suggest that to the server owner, but unfortunately it will  take days for approvals, IT tickets etc.

Comment: Could you check if you can (bulk) insert new rows into the table when this error occurs -- that is, can you continue inserting *now* or is it permanently borked while there's still disk space available? The latter would argue for "bug/error", the former for "it filled up but then space was reclaimed somehow". The DB doesn't have auto shrink enabled, right? Any other DBs on the same drive that might have ballooned, then been shrunk down?

Comment: @JeroenMostert: That's great suggestion and I had actually checked this few minutes before your comment: The error actually happens only for some inserts, and most of them do get inserted! Autoshrink is set to False.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. The only thing I can think of that potentially takes up lots of intermediate space is sorting the incoming bulk inserted rows, but that's proportional to the batch size of the inserts, not the data already available, so that shouldn't take up a lot. You could try experimenting with a smaller autogrowth value, especially if instant file initialization isn't enabled -- zeroing out 100 MB can take quite a bit of time. That should give timeout errors and not allocation errors, but... Just for sanity, I'd try a `DBCC CHECKDB` to verify all the metadata is in order.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, DavidG: I don't have 100% confirmation, but looking through the logs it seems that initially the HDD has indeed run out of space and the import got borked. Then someone increased the HDD space (without telling me), so it started importing again, and when I looked at it it had plenty of space. However, it still doesn't explain why after that some inserts were successful and some still produced the same error as before (insufficient disk space). It has been OK for the last 1 hour, all inserts are successful. Thanks for your suggestions.